# Right click and click and drag not working in Photoshop

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop, synergy, right-click

Right click and click and drag not working in Photoshop CS5 and only photoshop. Running windows 7 64bit.

Would synergy affect this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was happening to me as well, so I quit Synergy and it worked fine after restarting Photoshop.  I'm also running Win7 64 with Photoshop CS5 64-bit.

Comment: Thankyou! This was doing my head in. Forgot I had the synergy service set to automatic start.

Comment: Thank you. I coudn't find the problem anywhere, and your answer gave me the solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is a related issue being tracked.  See: http://synergy-foss.org/tracker/issues/467#note-12

Try setting up your server to use the synergy application instead of the service (if that applies).  It got my Photoshop cs5 working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen this happening in Google Chrome (v. 19): click-and-dragging to select text in the address bar fails - the initial click is registered, but no dragging ever occurs.

I have found that a temporary fix is to hit the Windows key twice (once to show the Start menu, then again to dismiss it). This doesn't fix it for long, but it's a faster & easier fix than restarting Synergy and/or Photoshop (I'm using CS4 on Win7 64-bit).